# Using ctr run gives error on starting a container

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, sudo, container

I am starting a container using the docker run command, it works fine. However when I try to start the same container using ctr command (irrespective of whatever snapshotter I use) I get this error:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

The error is coming from one of the lines in the dockerfile which is prepended by `sudo` . Please note that I tried removing sudo but then it gives permission denied error. As per my understanding docker engine uses ctr under the hood. Then why does not working for ctr? How shall I proceed to de